# in a nextjs app, how do I trigger a function in one component from another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Just like the title says, I've got 2 custom components on a page in a simple NextJS application:

```
<section>

   <CompA></CompA>
   <CompB></CompB>

</section>
```

How can I have a button in CompB trigger a function contained in CompA?

I assume I should use state somehow, but I'm a little lost how to do that in NextJS. Simple code example here: https://github.com/Chenzo/nextjs-comp-to-comp

Comment: I believe this approach is not logical, it's more convincing to call a function from parent component, not from another child component in the same level.

Comment: You can create a callback in the parent component(where you have the section) and pass the callback to both components. Each component can then invoke it to update for example shared state

Comment: Use global storage like Redux, and take a boolean and on change of that value call that function

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can do this with the `useImperativeHandle` hook, but this is not exactly the "React way":

```
const CompA = forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    doSmth: () => {
      console.log('CompA - function');
    },
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Component A</h2>
    </div>
  );
});

const CompB = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Component B</h2>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Trigger CompA function</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Home() {
  const compARef = useRef();
  const handleCompBClick = useCallback(() => compARef.current?.doSmth(), []);

  return (
    <section>
      <CompA ref={compARef}></CompA>
      <CompB onClick={handleCompBClick}></CompB>
    </section>
  );
}
```

As I wrote above, there is most likely a more correct way to solve your problem, avoiding the imperative approach. The decision will depend on what exactly components A and B will do in a real application.